# how to deal with seemingly paranoid behavior

Tags: management, communication

I have worked for 10 years for a small company, 28 employees. The owner, my manager, is kind-hearted and generous, sometimes to a fault, but on the flip-side, she has a tendency to default into thinking that people are taking advantage, stealing from her or will steal, or behaving suspiciously, when in fact she just doesn't have all the facts, so she makes knee-jerk decisions. Any suggestions on how to approach her about this, or even if I should?

Comment: How does this impact you, what type of decisions? It does not have to be bad to default into being suspicious. My boss does that (sometimes), and makes decision I disagree with, but are at the end harmless (and often useless, but if it makes him sleep better). In that case I just let it go. If it however would take away enjoyment out of my work and life, or if I believe the company is losing money because of it, then I might make work of it.

Comment: What are you hoping to accomplish? Are there specific behaviours that you would like to / need to see changed?

Comment: It's really normal for a successful proprietor to be "super cautious".  I would really say "it's standard".  It's like saying "my mother worries about us kids".  Try to support boss, see her view, and act in ways that assist her goals.  Enjoy!

Comment: Just what do you mean by "paranoid"?  Is there a hidden message in there?

Answer (score 1):

One of my former employer (and owner of the small company where I was working) drove to work 2 days after getting hemorrhoids surgery, when he was supposed to lay flat in bed and rest. Reason? He thought that without him watching on us we would slack the entire day and steal time from the company.

As an underling you can do pretty much nothing about this: anything you may say can trigger her paranoia into thinking you are plotting something against her, ending up in making your work life miserable.

If the paranoid behavior is annoying you and affects your working, I suggest:

Short term: try to make visible what and why you are doing things to deflect her paranoia from you.

Long term: search for a more healthy employment.

Comment: I find it ironic that it's not okay for employees to steal the time of their employers slacking off, but it ***is*** okay for employers to steal the time of their employees by requiring extra overtime without compensation.